# Green theorem - gauss theorem - cylinder sector.

Tags: gaussian-integral, greens-theorem

> 1) Compute, using green's theorem,
>
> $\int_\Gamma (xy+x+y)dx+(xy+x+y)dy$
>
> $\Gamma : \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ .
>
> 2) $f:R^3\to R^3,~f(x,y,z)=(z,x,-3y^2z)$ and $A=\partial\Omega$ the edge of the cylinder sector.
>
> $\Omega =${$(x,y,z)\in R^3 ;x\geq 0, y\geq 0, 0\leq z\leq 5, x^2+y^2\leq 16$}.
>
> Compute the flow of $f$ through $A$ directly and by using Gauss' theorem.

About 1: I haven't fully understood the green theorem yet. Can't I just set up a double integral with boundaries defined by $\Gamma$? Although I probably won't get any points for it since I need to use green theorem.

About 2: I'm kinda lost here. Firstly, I don't know what they mean by the cylinder sector. Are they talking about a disc cut off a cylinder or a smaller cylinder inside the original cylinder? Secondly, I don't know how to approach this kind of questions yet. Anyone got some tips or guidelines for these? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Regarding 1: Green's theorem allows to calculate the surface integral (here some ellipse) with a line integral over the boundary. That looks like the curve integral is given. You can choose the parametrization.

Regarding 2: This cylinder with extruded sector might help:

[image: cylinder with extruded sector]

You are supposed to calculate the flux $\Phi = \int\limits_E f \cdot dA$ through the edge surface $E$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Doesn't make it easier, but at least I can imagine the flow of f somehow.

Comment: Hm but looking at the task using Gauss theorem I start to think that "edge" here is used for the full boundary surface. You should ask, if possible, to clarify. Here the volume integral of the divergence of $f$ can be used to evaluate the flux.

Comment: Regarding 1: I tried integrating a quarter of the ellipse first and then multiplying it by 4 at the end. I set up my boundaries like this: 
$\int_0^1\int_0^{a\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}}(x+y+2)dxdy$. Are they correct? 


Regarding 2: I am kind of struggling to approach this problem. Don't know how to start or how to apply the formula for the flux.

Comment: Aren't I supposed to take $[\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy+x+y)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy+x+y)]dydx$?

Btw, I think my boundaries for dy are wrong. They should go from 0 to b, right?

Comment: So are the boundaries for dx okay?

Comment: You are right, I read a $+$ instead of a $-$.

Comment: Still seems wrong. My classmates say that the answer is supposed to be zero but with my current boundaries I got something different. Apparently I am not allowed to divide the ellipse in 4 quarters and then multiply it by 4.

Comment: Sure, for four quarters. You can split $\int\limits_A (y - x)\cdot dA = \int\limits_A y \cdot dA - \int\limits_A  x \cdot dA = 0 - 0$, due to symmetry each (think mean value).

Comment: And are your boundaries the same as mine from above?

Comment: I did not do a calculation. But I it is an ellipse with origin $(0,0)$ and that means that $y$ cancels with $-y$  along the $x$-axis  in the first, and $x$ cancels with $-x$ along the $y$-axis for the second integral.

Comment: True, so I guess my boundaries are wrong. How does one usually get the boundaries?

Comment: No your boundaries are ok. If you would calculate each sector, they would be something like $S_1 = uv$, $S_2=-uv$, $S_3=uv$, $S_4=-uv$. So their sum $S = S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + S_4$  would cancel. But you tried $S = 4 S_1$.

Comment: Okay, I did the calculations again and I still get an $\frac{a^2b}{3}$ as the result. I got that $\int_Ay\cdot dA=0$, but $\int_0^b\int_0^{a\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}}-xdxdy=\frac{a^2b}{3}$.

Comment: Check if $x$ and $y$ have the correct signs in each sector thus ++, -+, --, +-.

Comment: New boundaries: -b to b for dy and $-a\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$ to $a\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$ for dx. This way I get 0. 

Now I can finally go and deal with 2).

Comment: About 2): It says to calculate it 'directly' and using Gauss. Using Gauss I get the triple integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4\int_0^5-3y^3sin^2(\theta)dzdrd\theta=-240\pi$, because $div f=-3y^2$, right? Then what is the 'direct' way of calculating the flux? I suppose it's the formula you mentioned, $\int_E fdA$? But isn't that also a triple integral?

Comment: No it is a surface integral. Stokes connects surface int and curve int, Gauss volume int and surface int. Note that the contribution to the surface integral is $d\Phi = f \cdot dA$ where $dA$ is a surface vector. Have you asked your classmates what is meant with the edge? Only the rim surface or the whole boundary surface of the sector? Because then one would choose different volumes.

Comment: I think it's the whole boundary.